# Почему не работает функция JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```js
rockdrop(0);
rockdrop(1);

function rockdrop(Number) {
  for (i = Number; i <= Number; i++) {
    var rockSide = Math.round(Math.random() * (94 - 6) + 6);
    $rockItem = document.createElement('img');
    $gameTwo.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", $rockItem);
    $rockItem.setAttribute('id', "rock" + i);
    rockId = document.querySelector('#rock' + i);
    rockId.style.bottom = 575 + 'px';
    rockId.style.left = rockSide + '%';
    $rockItem.setAttribute('src', "./img/rock (1).svg");
    $rockItem.classList.add('rock');
    console.log(rockId);

    function drop() {
      rockId.style.bottom = parseInt(rockId.style.bottom) - 1 + 'px';
      if (parseInt(rockId.style.bottom) <= -53) {
        rockId.remove();
      }
    }
    setInterval(drop, 100);
  }
}
```

Как сделать что бы функция с новым элементом вызывалась отдельно?

Сейчас срабатывает так:
функция вызвана 2 раза с разными параметрами. консоль лог который вы видите показывает все как надо каждая функция с отдельным элементом. но внутренняя функция `drop` почему-то срабатывает только на самом первом вызове `rockdrop(0);`
Получается так: при запуске создаются два элемента с `id` `rock0` и `rock1` но `drop();` срабатывает только на элементе `rock1;` Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: а может быть такое что переменная  rockId при новом вызове функции переопределилась?

Comment: Код у вас, извините, очень странный. Во первых, почему у вас название параметра функции `Number`, оно совпадает с названием объекта (класса) Number в javascript, то есть вы затираете его область видимости. Во вторых вы используете цикл, который выполняется один раз? Для чего тогда вопрос? В третьих не понятно, где вы определяете `rockId` переменную, и, конечно, она переопределяется. Можете ее замкнуть в функции `drop` написав в первой строке, например. `const currentRockId = rockId;` и работать уже с `currentRockId`. Вообще по коду больше вопросов, чем ответов

Comment: это не может, а так и есть. Плюс непонятно почему ты определил только переменную rockSide, а остальные сделал глобальными